# How to scp without password prompt without storing private key

Tags: ssh, scp

Here is my current setup:

1. Connect to a Ubuntu server (Let's call this the server) from Windows
2. Do something interesting.
3. Send files from server 1 to another Ubuntu box (the box).

I used to store a private key on the server to allow password prompt-less scp, but I've been told that I'm not allowed to keep a private key on the server. Which brings us to my question:

EDIT: I should note that I'll be setting up a cronjob for most of scp processes.

How do I scp without password prompt without using private key or stdin method as shown in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872200/passing-the-password-as-a-parameter-in-a-scp-command

p.s. Not that this is a preferred method, but someone suggested ssh agent forwarding to achieve this, but I'm having trouble understanding what that is, and how it's applicable in my situation.

Comment: Take a look into agent forwarding here http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/putty-openssh.html#fwd

Comment: You are not allowed to keep a private key on `server`, but can you keep a private key on `box`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the windows machine? to run the cron job? can you keep a private key on the windows machine?

Comment: can you connect directly from the windows machine to `box` or do you have to connect through `server`?

Comment: @emory: I'm connecting to the ubuntu server from a windows machine. This is how I access the server, and yes I can keep the priv key on the windows machine. Also, yes I can connect to the box directly from the windows machine, but the goal is to run cronjobs in the server and push to the box.

Comment: Can you keep a private key on `box`?  Then you could pull to `box`.

Comment: No, I don't think so... thanks for all the ideas so far emory. If you have more, please keep'em coming!!

Comment: If the network connection between `box` and `server` is good, you can use my first answer.  Using your pasword, log into `box` from `server` and then don't log out.

Comment: I really think you should be looking into why you are not allowed o store a private key on `server`.  If there is a good reason, then for the same reason you probably don't want to bypass it.  If there is not a good reason, then using keys is easier and more secure thank any alternative I can come up with.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and I've been waiting for an answer from the dba :)

Comment: Not a solution to my question, but a solution to my goal:

I'm utilizing Dropbox API to transfer files between servers for anyone looking to do similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ssh with control master.  Create 2 entries in your config file like

Host box-master
ControlMaster yes
ControlPath $HOME/.ssh/ctrl_path
...

And

Host box-slave
ControlPath $HOME/.ssh/ctrl_path
Everything else should be the same

Using your password ssh into box-master.

You should be able to ssh/scp into box-slave without a password - until you log out of box-master.

This is useful if you can log in but need to do a bunch of ssh/scps and dont want  to continually reenter the password.

If your purpose is to do a bunch of scps this may also increase transfer speeds.  It may be the case you should be doing this for the speedup.

However from a security point of view it is inferior to using keys.

You can use the 2 in combination.  You put a passphrase on your key and use that to log into box-master.  It will prompt you for the keys passphrase.  Then you can log into box-slave with neither a passphrase nor a password.

Comment: This sounds like I need to log in first. What if I want to setup a cronjob? Any thoughts?

Comment: @chunsangh this is not really good for a cron job.  I thought your use case was that you logged in and then did a bunch of scps and you were tired of repetitively typing in the password.